# Why is the engraving (displace) after scaling no longer visible?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, displacement

I want do insert an engraving into a circle mesh (simplified example).

1. Create mesh
2. Add displace modifier
3. Add texture with single image

So far it works.

[image]

But after rescaling the engraving disappears. Why and how can I display the engraving again with scale=1?

[image]

I tried it with Crop, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: pls append blend file so we can check it out. thx

Comment: Thxs! How can I add a file?

Comment: Just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Chris Seriously? The classical "scale not applied" and you need a file? ;)

Comment: @PowerNow A file is not necessary.

Comment: Maybe he did it already and it didn’t help….‍♂️

Comment: @Chris Well, actually he did as the screenshots show, but that's exactly the problem. If the displacement is enough with scale 44, it's very tiny after applying the scale to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modifier works with the original data of the mesh as long as the scale is not applied.

So, let's say you have an object of 1 m. Scaled by 44 as your object, this is now 44 m. If the displacement would be set to 0.1 m, this results in 4.4 m displacement. Of course you can't set "0.1 m" in the modifier, just a strength, I just mean so that it would be displaced 0.1 m if the object was 1 m in size.

If you now apply the scale, the 44 m will become the original size of the object. But the *Displace* modifier doesn't automatically change its settings. So the displacement will be 0.1 m like before. Now this is very less displaced than 4.4 m compared to the overall size and in the case of your object with just a few milimeters it might even be hardly visible.

That's why it's always important to apply the scale when working with modifiers or tools that are using the original base mesh data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! That's exactly what I suspected yesterday and scaled my object back again. But why is the displacement based on the original size? Ultimately, only the absolute dimension counts and not the scaling value.

Comment: @PowerNow That's where you are mistaken... "Ultimately" - so finally, in the end when you finished modelling and maybe want to go from non-destructive to destructive changes in your mesh, then the absolute dimension counts. That's when you maybe want to apply everything. But if you want the effect of the modifier to stay the same as it is on the scaled object, you have to apply the modifier first and then apply the scale.

Comment: @PowerNow If you take the absolute dimension as the base, then for example the following would happen: say you round edges of a 2 m cube with the _Bevel_ modifier. You set the _Amount_ to 0.5 m because you like those really round edges. But then you see, the cube should be bigger. When you now scale it to 4 m but the modifier would stay at 0.5 m because that's the value you set it to (and you want it independent from the scale value), then you have to readjust the bevel amount as well or the edges are less round than before.

Comment: Yes thats of course correct. But on the other side if I use the Solidify modifier and select the correct Thickness than I need a scale=1. This was the reason I reset the scale.

Comment: @PowerNow Yes, but that's not "on the other side" - it's the same reason. The modifiers (the _Solidify_ as well as a _Bevel_ or a _Displace_ modifier) apply their settings to an object in relation to a scale of 1. The only difference is you had the scale at roundabout 44 and adjusted the _Displace_ to your liking so it looked as desired at scale 44 (but the setting was still based on scale 1). You could have done the same with the _Solidify_, 
 too - adjust the thickness so that it looks correct. It's just that you wanted a specific value which made it necessary to scale to 1.